# Accidentally deleted important SMS on Lumia 625, how can i get it back?

Tags: sms, backup

I've accidentally deleted an important sms from my Nokia Lumia 625. Anyone has an idea of how to recover it?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is not possible to recover deleted sms / texts as they are deleted in the cloud backup as well.